# How to cluster with Plotly and color based off of a column in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to use plotly to scatter the results of applying kmeans to dataframe and I want to color the scattered points based on the results of the kmeans. I am following this [this link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/397115_3d0c75c0bee741fc9026771a71b89c43.html) to use plotly but plotly is not coloring the scattered plots as I would like. Here is my code.

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

# generate the data
sample1_x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
sample1_y <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 1, sd = 1)
sample2_x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 1)
sample2_y <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 3, sd = 1)

# store the data in dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(sample1_x, sample1_y)
df2 <- data.frame(sample2_x, sample2_y)

df <- rbind(as.data.table(df1), as.data.table(df2), use.names = FALSE)
clusts <- kmeans(df, 2, 5)
clusts <- array(unlist(clusts), dim = c(2000, 1, 1))
df <- df %>%
    add_column(clusters = clusts)

# rename the columns
colnames(df)[1: 2] <- c("col1", "col2")

# plot
fig <- plot_ly(data = df,
               x = ~col1, y = ~col2,
               color = ~clusters,
               colors = c("red", "blue"),
               type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
fig
```

[image: This] is what plotly is returning, but what I want is [image: this].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `clusters` column is an `<array>` instead of a `<num>`.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(rnorm(1000, 0), rnorm(1000, 5)),
                 col2 = c(rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 3)))
setDT(df)
clusts <- kmeans(df, 2, 5)
df[, clusters := clusts$cluster]
plot_ly(data = df,
        x = ~col1, y = ~col2,
        color = ~clusters,
        colors = c("red", "blue"),
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```

[image: 2 dimesnional scatterplot of randomdata wherer colors coorsponds to the clusters from the kmeans analysis]